# add discussion comment to TFS via web-access

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access

How can you add notes/comments to the discussion box on the TFS web interface? There doesn't seem to be any "add input" field anywhere...

[image: TFS web interface discussion box hightlighted]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just misleading ui, you have to type your comment in the "History" box and save the TFS item to add a comment to the discussion box:

[image: TFS web interface how-to-add-a-comment]

Comment: Thank you! In retrospect that should have been obvious, but I couldn't figure it out either!